# Reasons for differences in memory consumption and performances of np.zeros and np.full

Tags: python, performance, numpy

When measuring memory consumption of `np.zeros`:

```
import psutil
import numpy as np

process = psutil.Process()
N=10**8
start_rss = process.memory_info().rss
a = np.zeros(N, dtype=np.float64)
print("memory for a", process.memory_info().rss - start_rss)
```

the result is unexpected `8192` bytes, i.e almost 0, while 1e8 doubles would need 8e8 bytes.

When replacing `np.zeros(N, dtype=np.float64)` by `np.full(N, 0.0, dtype=np.float64)` the memory needed for `a` are `800002048` bytes.

There are similar discrepancies in running times:

```
import numpy as np
N=10**8
%timeit np.zeros(N, dtype=np.float64)
# 11.8 ms ± 389 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
%timeit np.full(N, 0.0, dtype=np.float64)
# 419 ms ± 7.69 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

I.e. `np.zeros` is up to 40 times faster for big sizes.

Not sure these differences are for all architectures/operating systems, but I've observed it at least for x86-64 Windows and Linux.

Which differences between `np.zeros` and `np.full` can explain different memory consumption and different running times?

Comment: might also be interesting to add [`np.ones`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ones.html#numpy.ones) to the mix.

Comment: `np.zeros` in conjunction with the operating system is doing a 'lazy' initialization: `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27574881/why-does-numpy-zeros-takes-up-little-space

Comment: Short version: The answer is the same as the answer to [Why malloc+memset is slower than calloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2688466/364696). `calloc`/`numpy.zeros` doesn't actually *write* the memory at all at allocation time (for large enough allocations), `malloc`+`memset`/`numpy.full` does (in theory, it could special case `full` for zero values; in practice it appears not to).

Answer (score 3):

I don't trust `psutil` for these memory benchmarks, and rss (Resident Set Size) may not be the right metric in the first place.

Using stdlib [`tracemalloc`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tracemalloc.html) you can get correct looking numbers for memory allocation - it should be approx an 800000000 bytes delta for this N and float64 dtype:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import tracemalloc
>>> N = 10**8
>>> tracemalloc.start()
>>> tracemalloc.get_traced_memory()  # current, peak
(159008, 1874350)
>>> a = np.zeros(N, dtype=np.float64)
>>> tracemalloc.get_traced_memory()
(800336637, 802014880)
```

For the timing differences between `np.full` and `np.zeros`, compare the man pages for `malloc` and `calloc`, i.e. the `np.zeros` is able to go to [an allocation routine which gets zeroed pages](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.18.1/numpy/core/src/multiarray/ctors.c#L987). See [`PyArray_Zeros`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.18.1/numpy/core/src/multiarray/ctors.c#L3085) --> calls [`PyArray_NewFromDescr_int`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.18.1/numpy/core/src/multiarray/ctors.c#L993) passing in `1` for the `zeroed` argument, which then has [a special case](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.18.1/numpy/core/src/multiarray/ctors.c#L1155-L1160) for allocating zeros faster:

```
if (zeroed || PyDataType_FLAGCHK(descr, NPY_NEEDS_INIT)) {
    data = npy_alloc_cache_zero(nbytes);
}
else {
    data = npy_alloc_cache(nbytes);
}
```

It looks like `np.full` does not have this fast path. There the performance will be similar to first doing an init and then doing a copy *O(n)*:

```
a = np.empty(N, dtype=np.float64)
a[:] = np.float64(0.0)
```

`numpy` devs could presumably have added a fast path to `np.full` if the fill value was zero, but why bother to add another way to do the same thing - users could just use `np.zeros` in the first place.

Comment: I trust more psutils than tracemalloc (https://stackoverflow.com/q/50148554/5769463) even if for numpy the memory usage should be recorded correctly. However, tracemalloc doesn't show the really commited memory - I think OS knows best how much memory is really in use.

Comment: I also doubt there is a much faster way to zero memory than used by np.full (python/numpy overhead doesn't play a huge role here) - otherwise np.full would use it. In your measurements, np.zeros would zero memory with about 53333GB/s which is not possible.

Comment: Hmm, you are right about `np.zeros`, there must be something else going on here - I'll delete that part of my answer and keep investigating. I should have checked the absolute numbers more carefully. Maybe some lazy init hidden somewhere.

Comment: @wim: It's almost certain that the large pre-zeroed allocation is faster because it's relying on the OS providing pre-zeroed pages. The same way `calloc` can be `malloc`+`memset` for small allocations, but plain `malloc` for large allocations (large enough to make a dedicated request for memory from the OS, e.g. via Windows' `VirtualAlloc` or UNIX-like's anonymous `mmap`) with no zeroing step. On Linux, those pages are copy-on-write mappings of the zero page, which means the first write to each page is more expensive; `np.full` would force the early copy, and have consistent write performance.

Comment: @wim: Yeah, just checked. If there's no cached zeroed data in the bucketed free list, `npy_alloc_cache_zero` defers to `PyDataMem_NEW_ZEROED`. `PyDataMem_NEW_ZEROED`'s primary work is done via a `calloc` call, which has the optimizations I mentioned on most allocators.

Comment: @ShadowRanger  That looks correct on Linux. Not sure if such a magic trick ("here's one I've prepared earlier") is avail on other platforms, though.

Comment: @wim: Aside from embedded systems, all OSes I know of provide zeroed memory from the OS-specific allocation methods (that `malloc`/`calloc` use directly when large requests are made). It's a security measure; they don't want data left in the memory from the last process that had it. Whether its lazy zeroing (page is COW of zero page, copied immediately before write) or eager (kernel thread zeroes pages, with allocations blocking if not enough available) differs from OS to OS, but it's always zeroed. See [Why malloc+memset is slower than calloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2688466/364696)

Comment: @ShadowRanger  Interesting.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The **numpy.zeros** function straight uses the C code layer of the Numpy library while the functions **ones** and **full** works as same by initializing an array of values and copying the desired value in it.

Then the **zeros** function doesn't need any language interpretation while for the others, **ones** and **full**, the Python code need to be interpreted as C code.

Have a look on the source code to figure it out by yourself: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/core/numeric.py

Comment: sorry, I was using french language :)